# Running programs with sudo gives Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCannot open display:

Tags: sudo, root

I'm trying to run `pcmanfm` with root privileges, but I keep getting the error:

> Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyCannot open display:

I saw somebody suggest `export DISPLAY=desktop:0`, but that gives me the error:

> keyCannot open display:

Comment: Try `xhost +local:` before running it. Try also `export DISPLAY=:1.0`.

Comment: xhost +local worked, but why did I need to in the first place? Will this solve it permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was running `xhost +local:`.

Explanation: The `xhost` program is used to add and delete host names or user names
to the list allowed to make connections to the X server, as
a rudimentary form of security for a workstation.

To provide access to an application running as `sudo` or `su` to the
graphical server (meaning your X session and your computer screen),
open a terminal and type as normal user:

```
$ xhost +local:
```

To get things back to normal, with controlled access to the X screen:

```
$ xhost -
```

Source: [Xhost - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xhost).

Comment: for me not. check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659362/how-to-generate-correctly-a-new-xauthority-file-for-a-display-missing-it-witho . Newest installations of debian make as default `easy` as hostname for whatever reasons. this created a lot problems for me. check sysctl.conf, set `kernel.hostname=NAME`, and populate changes in bashrc adding `sysctl -p --system -w`. Also, `cat .Xauthority` to check what is the hostname given there. But sysctl was not needed if i edit that here `sudo nano /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp3s0.leases` and change it.